# how to find why the syntax error occur & how to achieve a globalize format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-globalize

Here is my code,

```
Globalize.format(50.635676576567%, 'n2')
```

it throw syntax error because of **%** has been added in number. but i need to show the output as 50.64%. how to achieve generic way{note: the symbol can be anything like character or special number anything...}

Example:

```
Globalize.format(50.635676576567%, 'n2') = 50.64%
Globalize.format(50.635676576567C, 'n2') = 50.64C
Globalize.format(50.635676576567@, 'n2') = 50.64@
Globalize.format($50.635676576567, 'n2') = $50.64
Globalize.format(#50.635676576567, 'n2') = #50.64
Globalize.format(50.635676576567world, 'n2') = 50.64 world
```

how to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code. You must split the characters and numbers to perform globalize format

```
var str = "Globalize.format(50.635676576567world, 'n2') Globalize.format($50.635676576567, 'n2') ",
substr;

while (str.indexOf('Globalize.format(') >= 0) {
   substr = str.substring(str.indexOf('Globalize.format('), str.indexOf(")") + 1);
   var calculate = substr.substring(substr.indexOf('(') + 1, substr.indexOf(",")),
   character = calculate.replace(/[0-9.]/g, ''),
   numberic = calculate.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''),
   index = calculate.indexOf(character),
   formatedString = substr.replace(character, "");
   if (index == 0)
      formatedString = character + eval(formatedString);
   else
      formatedString = eval(formatedString) + character;
   str = str.replace(substr, formatedString);
}
console.log(str);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You would only add the symbol on output, i.e:

```
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') + '%' = "50.64%"
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') + 'C' = "50.64C"
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') + '@' = "50.64@"
'$' + Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') = "$50.64"
'#' + Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') = "#50.64"
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2') + ' world' = "50.64 world"
```

Comment: thanks.. it will work but due to some scenario i need to use like that format..(Globalize.format(50.635676576567C, 'n2')) how to achieve from this format..
in my scenario i m converting like that,

var format = "(Globalize.format(50.635676576567C, 'n2')";
var a = eval(format);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the necessary symbol after applying the `Globalize.format`

```
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2')+'%';
Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2')+'C';
'#'+Globalize.format(50.635676576567, 'n2');
```

And so on.

Comment: thanks.. it will work but due to some scenario i need to use like that format..(Globalize.format(50.635676576567C, 'n2')) how to achieve from this format..
in my scenario i m converting like that,

var format = "(Globalize.format(50.635676576567C, 'n2')";
var a = eval(format);